# How to use vue.js and firebase (directory-structure)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, directory, directory-structure

When you install firebase, the 'public' folder and 'index.html' are created automatically. I'm not sure where to put the 'public' folder in the current vue project file structure. The 'localhost: 8080' screen is displaying correctly, but the screen using firebase hosting is not showing.

This path is a Vue project. C:\Users\username\public\vue-project

And this path is a Firebase's 'public' folder. C:\Users\username\public

Then I ran 'firebase deploy' in cmd.

1. cd C:\Users\username>firebase deploy
   [image]
2. cd C:\Users\username\public>firebase deploy
   [image]

Comment: One approach is to have two different projects: one for Firebase, one for your Vue.js app. Then you paste the files generated by the vue.js process into the Firebase’s public folder and deploy the project.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Is it correct to put the whole folder of the vue project into the "public" folder?  I will try it.  Thank you for your comment on this question :)

Comment: Yes indeed, the whole content of the `dist` folder.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec 
I added the result to the question. I would appreciate if you see it.

Comment: It seems you are not in your Firebase project. You have to follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup and in particular Step 4

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I saw and followed the URL in the comment you posted, and there was no error when I ran 'firebase deploy'. Despite the flimsy explanation, thanks for helping me get started with Firebase :)
But when I enter the domain, the Welcome page comes up. (The content of public \ index.html.) What settings do I need to make the pages of my existing Vue.js project appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you mention in your comments above, you still see the default Firebase "Welcome" page it means that probably you didn't overwrite it correctly.

You should put the entire content of your vue.js `dist` folder (generated through `npm run build`) into the `public` folder of Firebase hosting (and overwrite the default `index.html` file initially generated by the Firebase project setup script).

Then in you `firebase.json` file you have the following rewrite in order to handle the Single Page Application behavior of you vue.js application.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    ...
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the 'dist' folder well. This issue has not been resolved for a week. But thanks to you I solved this problem. Thank you very much for your help :)